# Unable to use inherited/isolated scope concept in my example plunker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am learning inherited/isolated scopes in angular directives and struck with some basic concepts. please see the plunker below.

[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/V7875jsEx7hKqDwegva1?p=preview).

Scenario1:

I have 2 directives (book and details). I am displaying two "Book Details" containers and toggling book name by sending custom attributes like this.

```
 <book bookdetails="book" collapsed="yes" list="list"></book> 
 <book bookdetails="book1" collapsed="no" list="list"></book>
```

Question: Is this the right way to handle displaying things in 2 different containers?

Scenario 2:

I want to hide the author details section in container 1 but show in container2 on load. How to accomplish that?

When I use this line below it will hide and show both author details section but I want to keep it separate.

```
<details collapsed="yes"></details>
```

I know I am lacking basic skills using inherited/isolated scopes. Can someone educate me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK to use nested directives like you've used so you can do everything related to the details pane in the details controller like removing items from the books list.

If you wouldn't do any logic in details controller and just include some html I would just use `ng-include`.

Some points I've detected during improving your code:

- Template markups are partial html files, so no need to add header, body etc. Just add your markup that you need in your directive.
- I've created one model array `books` that you can iterate with `ng-repeat` and not two separate scope variables. That's easier to add more books.
- I wouldn't pass the collapsed state to directive isolated scope. I would add it to the book model then you can have independent states of the details panes.
  You could also create a collapsed array scope variable separate from your model and use it like `ng-hide='collapsed[$index]'` if you don't like to add it to your model.
- Don't compare to the string `yes`. It makes things more complicated. It's better to use `true` or `false`.
- The list you're passing is OK if you'd like to use one list for every details pane. But I think you need them independent from each other so add it to your book model.
- For toggeling a value you can use the js shorthand: `collapsed = !collapsed;`. It takes the value of collapsed and inverts it and re-asigns it to collapsed.
- Details directive: You don't need to pass attributes to a directive that doesn't use isolated scope. Instead you can directly use the inherited scope of the parent.

**Note**: I think you should have a look at `angular-ui-bootstrap` and use an accordion instead of your manually created panes later. But for learning directives your code is OK.

Please have a look at your updated code below or in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cW1SU9Ju9JNYpAtVgIVL?p=preview).

If something is not clear, feel free to add a comment and I'll try to help.

```js
angular.module('plunker', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.books = [{
      id: 0,
      name: 'Building modern ASP.NET 5',
      author: {
        name: 'name1',
        age: 31,
        country: 'USA'
      },
      collapsed: false,
      list: [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'book1'
      }, {
        id: 1,
        name: 'book2'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'book3'
      }]
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: 'AngularJS',
      author: {
        name: 'name2',
        age: 27,
        country: 'USA'
      },
      collapsed: true,
      list: [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'book1'
      }, {
        id: 1,
        name: 'book2'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'book3'
      }]
    }];
    //$scope.list =  ["book1", "book2", "book3"];
  }).directive('book', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'book.html',
      scope: {
        bkdet: "=bookdetails"
          //list: "="
          //collapsed: "@"
      },
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.toggleDetails = function() {
          $scope.bkdet.collapsed = !$scope.bkdet.collapsed;
          updateCaption();
        };

        function updateCaption() {
          $scope.hypshowhide = $scope.bkdet.collapsed ? 'show details' : 'hide details';
        }

        // first run
        updateCaption();
        /*if ($scope.collapsed == 'yes')
        {
            $scope.dethide = true;
        }
        else {
            $scope.dethide = false;
        }        */
        //$scope.hypshowhide = 'show details';
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('details', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'details.html',
      controller: function($scope) {
        /*console.log($scope.bkdet.collapsed);
        if (!$scope.bkdet.collapsed) { //== 'yes') {
            $scope.dethide = true;
        }
        else {
            $scope.dethide = false;
        }*/

        $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
          $scope.bkdet.list.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="container">
      <book bookdetails="book" ng-repeat="book in books"></book>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="book.html">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h1>Book Details</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <a class="pull-right" href="#" ng-click="toggleDetails(collapsed)">{{hypshowhide}}</a>
          <div>
            <!--ng-hide="dethide">-->
            {{bkdet.name}}
          </div>
          <!--<details collapsed="no"></details>-->
          <details></details>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="details.html">
    <div class="container" ng-hide="bkdet.collapsed">
      <div class="row">
        <ul class="list-group list-unstyled">
          <!--<li>
            <h1>Author:</h1>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>-->
          <li>
            <strong>Author</strong>
            {{bkdet.author.name}}

          </li>
          <li>

            <strong>Age</strong>
            {{bkdet.author.age}}

          </li>
          <li>
            <strong>Country</strong>
            {{bkdet.author.country}}
          </li>
          <li>
            <div ng-if="bkdet.list.length == 0">
              <p>No books here!</p>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="c in bkdet.list">
              <p>
                {{c.name}}&nbsp;
                <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeItem($index)">X</button>
              </p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <!--</ul>
        </li>-->

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```